# Is it possible to apply animation to a text which is dynamically getting appended using pure css?

Tags: angular, html, css

I am trying to add animation to a text content which appends dynamically. I need to apply animation to each incoming text, keeping the already added text stable

Comment: Yes it is. Take a look at [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Comment: i referred animate.css, but the effect can be applied to the whole block right? If am having a text ABC and i need to append XYZ next, the XYZ needs to have the animation. Next i need to add PQR, so ABCXYZ should stay stable and PQR needs to animate. Like that. Am new to CSS

Comment: it is solved. i added an ngclass and pushed the text. matching the index to the last item and applied the animation to it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push the text content to an array. You can try ngClass and match the index with the last element using ternary operator, apply the animation to the matching span.